# Accessing textarea value inside td on iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm freaking out with an issue I cannot solve.

I don't have so much experience with iFrames and jQuery but it's needed to solve this asap because it's a big problem in an app.

I've an iFrame with a div and some rows. I've a textarea and a button whos calling a javascript method who's recovering the value inserted in textarea

But it's not working, either of options I tried have worked.

This is the code, could you help me?

Thank you!

http://pastebin.com/xsWzG2VH

EDIT:

I'm trying to recover the value of TEXTOAYUNTAMIENTO, a textarea inside td structure with that function.

When I press the button to recover it, all of them are empty or null.

This is the method:

```
  function checkayuntamiento(value)
        {
                alert(value);
                alert('Hola');
                alert($('#TEXTOAYUNTAMIENTO', window.parent.document).html());
                alert('<%=indice%>');
                alert('<%=TEXTOAYUNTAMIENTO%>');
                alert('<%=DESCMODOENVIO%>');
                var valor = document.getElementById("TEXTOAYUNTAMIENTO");
                var valor5 = document.getElementsByName('TEXTOAYUNTAMIENTO')[0].value
                var valor2 = document.getElementById("TEXTOAYUNTAMIENTO").innerHTML;
                //var elem = $('#salida_'+id);
                var idi = $("#TEXTOAYUNTAMIENTO").val();
                var asdf = $(this).closest('tr').next().find(".AYUNTAMIENTOS").val();
                                        var valor3 = document.getElementById("PRUEBA");
                var valor4 = document.getElementById("PRUEBA").innerHTML;
                //var elem = $('#salida_'+id);
                var idi2 = $("#PRUEBA").val();
                var asdf2 = $(this).closest('td').next().find(".PRUEBA").val();
                alert(asdf);
                alert(idi);
                alert(valor);
                alert(valor2);
                alert(asdf2);
                alert(idi2);
                alert(valor3);
                alert(valor4);
                alert(valor5);
        }
```

Comment: I suggest you isolate the issue and post only the code involved in that issue

Comment: Please give us the relevant part of your code for this issue. Nobody likes to read 782 lines of code.

Comment: I just did it, check again the post please.

Comment: try `$("#TEXTOAYUNTAMIENTO").text()` and `$("#TEXTOAYUNTAMIENTO").html()` the text area's id should be "TEXTOAYUNTAMIENTO"

Comment: rps...not working. Neither of them, I changed TextArea to "TEXTOAYUNTAMIENTO" but not working...

Comment: By the way, this textarea is inside a td structure

Comment: your code is fine [check this link](http://jsfiddle.net/7esp7/) and it being inside a td is not a problem, are there any other elements with the same id?